# How does msiexec with /a and /qb work without admin access

Tags: python, windows-installer

I installed Python on a PC using [instructions here](http://spointeau.blogspot.com/2013/09/python-install-without-admin-rights.html?showComment=1435586364918#c1380062267303062647), running below command, without admin credentials prompt.

```
msiexec /a python-3.3.2.msi /qb TARGETDIR=%TARGET%
```

Parts of Python (e.g. PIP), which need admin access, seem to be missing.

From msiexec documentation, /qb will install with basic UI, but it doesn't mention skipping the credentials prompt and its impact.

So, what part of this command made the requirement for admin credentials go away?

Is this a general trick for other msi installers too, where we are prompted for admin credentials, but installation will carry on without admin access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

msiexec /a isn't what you'd call an installation. An administrative installation just unpacks all the files into the target location, but it's basically just that - an unpack and a file copy. You won't find an entry in Programs&Features; if the setup creates registry entries or shortcuts you won't see them either. If there are files destinmed for the GAC, the common files folder and so on you won't find them there. There's no trick, no security breach.

Comment: Just don't try to set TARGETDIR to a path you don't have access to.  I typically set it to %CD%\EXTRACT